# How to get only the "title" from JSON file

Tags: php, json, foreach

I have this structure (It's a **stdClass**):

```
  stdClass Object
(
    [TitleA] => stdClass Object
        (
            [key1] => value1
            [key2] => value2
            [key3] => value3
        )

    [TitleB] => stdClass Object
        (
            [key1] => value1
            [key2] => value2
        )
)
```

**EDIT 1** 
Thanks to @John Ellmore I transformed the readen json into associative array, so now I have this:

```
Array
(
    [TitleA] => Array
        (
            [key1] => value1
            [key2] => value2
            [key3] => value3
        )

    [TitleB] => Array
        (
            [key1] => value1
            [key2] => value2
        )
)
```

I'm able to loop and work throught the `keys` and `values` but I need to identify whether the currenct loop iteraction is or is not the last one.

```
 $myFile  = fopen($sourceFile, "r") or die("Unable to open the file !");
 $content = json_decode(fread($myFile, filesize($sourceFile)));
 fclose($myFile);      
 foreach( $content as $keys => $value ) {
  //This loop allows me to work around with the keys     

   foreach($value as $index => $key) {
      // And this loop allows me to work with the values
   }  
 }
```

What I need to do is identify when I'm working on the last `title` on my loop. I thought I could use [php end() function](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.end.php) which worked to get last keys inside each iteration. But I can't do the same to get the last Title name.
So I could compare the last one with the current one and them I'd know if I'm current looping throught the last one or not.

Is it possible to list them in some sort of array or something alike ?

Comment: It might be helpful to decode your JSON data to associative arrays, not objects. E.g. `json_decode($json, true)` (the second parameter being boolean `true`).

Comment: Vote++; Thank you ! Would that easy things for me to get where I need? I'll try to mess around it now

Comment: I think you could simply count your iterations (i.e. create a counter variable and increase it by one each iteration). This counter you could then compare against `count($array)`. There is also ways to find the last element of an array (the PHP manual for the `end()` function contains multiple in the comments), but as this changes the internal array pointer, I would not recommend doing so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`end()`](https://php.net/end) and [`key()`](https://php.net/key) to get the last title of your object.

```
$content=json_decode('{"titleA":{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2","key3":"val3"},"titleB":{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2"}}');

end($content); // place the cursor on the last position
$last_title = key($content); // get the key of the current position
// here, $last_title = 'titleB'

foreach( $content as $keys => $value ) {

    $is_last_title = $keys == $last_title;

    var_dump($keys, $is_last_title);

    //This loop allows me to work around with the keys

    foreach($value as $index => $key) {
      // And this loop allows me to work with the values
    }
}
```

Will outputs:

```
string(6) "titleA"
bool(false)
string(6) "titleB"
bool(true)
```

This will also works with arrays.

Comment: Just and  "add". `end()` wont't work in this case, with stdClass or Array. Had to group those titles first, then I did as you showed.

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro I used a variable to store the result of `end()`, but I didn't use it. I've used `key()`, just after to get the key of the last element.

Comment: Ohhh I get it now!! Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome @PlayHardGoPro :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `end` as you suggested. That will move the internal array pointer to the last element. Then you can use `key` to get the key at that position.

```
end($content);
$lastKey = key($content);
```

You can compare the current key to that key value as you iterate `$content`.

```
foreach ($content as $keys => $value) {
    if ($keys === $lastKey) echo 'Last One';
    // etc.
}
```

---

If you have decoded to an array rather than an object, you can also dereference the result of `array_keys` with the array count - 1 to get the last key. I like the `end`/`key` method more because it doesn't create another array you're probably never going to use, but some people like fewer lines of code, so here's that:

```
$lastKey = array_keys($content)[count($content) - 1];
```

Comment: Interestingly, I saw your answer before the one of @Syscall.

Comment: _"internal array pointer"_ is the right term.

Comment: @Syscall I think it's interesting that it works on objects just as well.

Comment: `end()` doesn't work to get the last `title`. I had to use another function to group them first. But i did the same thing as you guys showed. Just needed to gather those titles. Yaay /o/

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro `end` doesn't work by itself because it returns the array value at the end, and the title you're trying to get is the key. But since `end` moves the array pointer to the end, calling `key` after it will get the last key.

Comment: Nice!! I'll try to work with that.

Comment: Yes @Don'tPanic, It's really interesting. All function of this "family" works with objects, even in PHP4 ;)